How to propagate the changes from Room when I perform an update?
I have 7 items in Room and I want to update the name of one item. Here is what I have tried:
interface ItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table")
    fun getItems(): Flow<List<Item>>

    @Update
    fun updateItem(item: Item)
}

My repo is very simple:
interface ItemRepository {
    fun getItems(): Flow<List<Item>>

    fun updateItem(item: Item)
}

Inside the ViewModel I have:
class ItemsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: ItemRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val itemsResultFlow = flow {
        repo.getItems().collect { items ->
            try {
                emit(Result.Success(items))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emit(Result.Failure(e))
            }
        }
    }

    var updateItemResult by mutableStateOf<Result<Unit>>(Result.Loading)
        private set

    fun updateItem(item: Item) = viewModelScope.launch {
        updateItemResult = try {
            Result.Success(repo.updateItem(item))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.Failure(e)
        }
    }
}

And inside the composable I have:
val itemsResponse by viewModel.itemsResultFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(Result.Loading)

Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        //  
    },
    content = {
        when(val itemsResponse = itemsResponse) {
            is Result.Loading -> CircularProgressIndicator()
            is Result.Success -> {
                items(
                    items = itemsResponse.data
                ) { item ->
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
            is Result.Error -> print(result.e)
        }
    }
)

The app works fine but it loads the entire list of items each time I update a single item, which is not what I want. To get rid of this, I made some changes in ViewModel:
private var _items = MutableStateFlow<Result<List<Item>>>(Result.Loading)
val items: StateFlow<Result<List<Item>>> = _items.asStateFlow()

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repo.getItems().collect { items ->
            try {
                _items.value = Response.Success(items)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _items.value = Response.Failure(e)
            }
        }
    }
}

And inside the composable:
val itemsResponse by viewModel.items.collectAsState()

The app compiles without any errors, but when I update the name of an item, I cannot see the updated name in the list, unless I close and reopen the app. How to see the updated value in the list without the need to load the entire list of items?
Update
Here is the call in the repo class:
fun getItems(): Flow<List<Item>>

And here is the call in the repo implementation class:
override fun getItems() = itemDao.getItems()


Can i see your repository   repo.getItems() this? ItemRepository

@SanthoshKumar I just updated my question with repo.getItems(). Can you please take a look?


[...] it loads the entire list of items each time I update a single item, which is not what I want.

I'm note sure about the reasons why you do not want this, but in general you should let the database optimize how to update the flows if something changed. Only when you have manifest performance issues you should refactor your app to address this.
One way would be to remove the flows from your DAO so the list isn't automatically updated anymore. You would then need to do the updates yourself whenever a change occurs. Make sure to encapsulate this logic in the repository so the rest of your app still only has a Single Source of Truth (i.e. the Repo should still emit a Flow<List<Item>>, it just needs to construct the list itself whenever an item is changed).
If your issue is caused by a very large list of thousands and thousands of items (it probably is not because you say you only have 7, but nevertheless..) and you cannot restrict them using a WHERE clause in your DAO, then the proper way would be to use the Paging library. In that case the database will only return chunked data, effectively providing multiple sublists. When an item is changed only the sublist that contains the item will be retrieved again.
The solution you proposed doesn't address the issue because it still collects the getItems() flow. So whatever the rest of the code does, you already get an entire new list when a single item changes (which, just to emphasize it again, usually isn't a problem).
And as a final note, please do not use MutableState in the view model, there are some nasty edge cases where this won't work as intended. You can replace it with MutableStateFlow if you want to keep the same functionality.

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. So you basically say that there is no problem in loading the same list over and over again when I simply update a single item?

Yes. Look at it from the other side: In the UI you do need a List. And it needs to be an immutable list (which is quite performant, btw.), otherwise it won't properly work with Compose. So whenever a single element in the list changes you need a new list. That are the basic requirements coming from the UI. To satisfy that you can just use the Room flow. just call stateIn on it in the view model and you're done. Only when the list is extremely large you want to consider paging it for performance reasons. Everything else is premature optimization.

I understand your point of view. I'm just having 7 items in Room for testing purposes, but in time, there will be much more. I remember when I was working with RecyclerView, I could notify the adapter about a single change, meaning that I could draw on the screen only the item that was changed and not the entire list. This is exactly what I want to avoid in the future. What do you think (as a last question)?

Drawing the UI is handled by Compose now, you do not actively do anything, you just tell Compose what the current state is. But Compose will skip everything that didn't change, so in the end it's still only the one, changed item that will be redrawn. But you have to provide an entire new list to Compose. As already mentioned, creating a new list is cheap (there is only one new item in the list, the other items are the same objects, they are just put into a new list), the performance impact will be hard to measure and virtually impssible for the user to to notice.

After some investigation, I realized you need to add the suspend modifier to @Update function to ensure that the updated item is emitted instantly when you update it, but I am unsure if this is the correct approach. Here is the code I'm working with:
@Dao
interface ItemDao {
    @Update
    suspend fun updateItem(item: Item)
}


On your way,
private var _items = MutableStateFlow<Result<List<Item>>>(Result.Loading)
val items: StateFlow<Result<List<Item>>> = _items.asStateFlow()

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repo.getItems().collect { items ->
            try {
                _items.value = Response.Success(items)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _items.value = Response.Failure(e)
            }
        }
    }
}

And inside the composable:
val itemsResponse by viewModel.items.collectAsState()

Now the updated item will be included instantly.
Also, it is not a problem loading the entire list again after an update, but you need to optimize this in your LazyColumn using the key parameter. This will reduce unnecessary recompositions of items that haven't changed, rather than recomposing the updated item.

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question and trying to help but I already have the suspend added in front of the updateItem function. I have also added the key parameter but there is no difference.
